# Ionic 2 signalr is not connecting with hub

Tags: ionic2, signalr

i am using library 'signalr-no-jquery' in ionic2 with visual studio 2015 . I'm using the following code .

Import:

`import { hubConnection } from 'signalr-no-jquery';`

Code:

```
    console.log("Stage 1");
    var connection =new  hubConnection('http://192.168.0.213:9000');

    console.log("Stage 2");

    var hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('broadcaster');
    console.log("Stage 3");

    connection.start({ jsonp: true })
        .done(() => {
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);

        })
        .fail(() => { console.log('Could not connect'); });
```

Every time it goes in fail and write console 'Could not connect'. Any suggestion what i'm doing wrong ?

Library link:

[https://github.com/DVLP/signalr-no-jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cLNJ.png)

I have searched but did not find any solution . Any suggestion?

**Note:**
 At server side i'm using c# web api . and hub is configured and it's working fine with angular1 as a client.But same is not working with my ionic2 app.

**Update 1**

Here is chrome network response .

**Request 1**

Request URL:

> http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//192.168.0.213%3A9000/signalr/negotiate%3FclientProtocol%3D1.5%26connectionData%3D%255B%255D

Response:

[image: Request 1 response]

**Request 2**

Request URL:

> http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//192.168.0.213%3A9000/signalr/connect%3Ftransport%3DlongPolling%26clientProtocol%3D1.5%26connectionToken%3DCfDJ8HpWfXipicxHvZ8CCLKyWJkObE4lFrYrJehJly%252BSs8%252BNamgEaPH0GDQkZlsZXuYxn32TZOpm4cmPzLeOYq1zTPBXpU5sxK3pF%252FONkllddO1ivhI2hur79Hr4YWVYJ45K7Bukm2R2JZXtn0FF%252FFOtl798xyA7i4UL1Ufz4ZfkAOsN%26connectionData%3D%255B%255D

Response

`The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.`

[image: [1]: https://github.]

Comment: In the network tab of chrome what do you see as the response?

Comment: What is the first request and what is the second request url? It seems negotation fails at first?

Comment: @misha130 it look strange why at first request response is good as expected but next some are not ?  it's a library issue ?

Comment: You said it works with angularjs so I can't really blame the webapi for this. But the requests look exactly as they should. I mean the connectionToken is there and its in the correct format. What if you compare the differences between the requests of the angularjs and this?

Comment: Angular1 client side is deploy and working fine  with same hub as im using right now . Now client want me to connect a new ionic 2 app with same hub.

Comment: Is it the same library though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143566/discussion-between-usman-lqbal-and-misha130).